# Eclipse error: "unable to perform synchronized check with remote server"

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse is giving me this error when I try to copy an object back to the Force.com server:
"unable to perform synchronize check with remote server
Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out
Your project may be out of sync."

This is my first try at using Eclipse, so it may not be set up right.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Edit: screenshot of trying to deploy:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow the steps below:**

**1.** Right click on your project.
**2.** Go with Force.com-->Deploy to server.
**3.** You get the error here.
**4.** Re-enter the credentials - and if it still does not work you have 2 approaches.

**2 Approaches:**
**1.** Use any other user's credentials to see if it actually works.
**2.** Create a new project with a different name, make changes and deploy.

**Ensure that you are using the proper security token! If unsure, generate a new one.** This should help.

Comment: I'm doing that. It gave me a whole list of 284 deployment candidates. Why would that be? I only changed one object!

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right. Screenshot it to the question. THanks!

Comment: See my screenshot above

Comment: Have these components changed since the project was fetched locally? If they have, they need to be resync'd .

Comment: No - the only thing I changed is Contact.Object

Comment: When I right  click on the project and click Refresh from Server, I get that same error - invalid login etc.

Comment: I deleted the project and started again, and I think it works now. THanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. :)