# Eclipse with Salesforce - can't Refresh from Server

Tags: eclipse

I just set up Eclipse with Salesforce, and when I try to Refresh from Server, it tells me 
"unable to perform synchronize check with remote server Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out Your project may be out of sync."

When I try to Deploy to Server, it gives me that, and then asks for my password, and then it works. But when I try to refresh from server, it just gives me that error and then doesn't ask for anything.

Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit:**

I asked a similar question before [Eclipse error: "unable to perform synchronized check with remote server"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16570/eclipse-error-unable-to-perform-synchronized-check-with-remote-server), that solution worked then, but it's not working anymore.

Edit: Is anyone out there? I reinstalled windows on my computer, reinstalled Force.com IDE, and I still cannot get this to work.

Comment: @Ralph - the same question, the same user, and a different scenario now.

Comment: Edit: Is anyone out there? I reinstalled windows on my computer, reinstalled Force.com IDE, and I still cannot get this to work.

Comment: I don't think anybody is responding because you haven't added any new information; there is nothing new to use to help troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: What other information could I add? I think I told everything that applies - if there's a specific thing that you want to know can you ask?